# Parsererror : expected identifier but got ";"

Tags: solidity, remix

I CHANGE THIS:

modifier onlyOwner() {
    if (msg.sender != owner) {
      throw;
    }
    _;
  }

TO THIS:

modifier onlyOwner() {
         require(msg.sender == owner);
             _;
            }
    _;
    }

And i receive this error in REMIX:
Parsererror : expected identifier but got ";"

_;

Please help help

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want the following:

```
modifier onlyOwner() { 
    require(msg.sender == owner); 
    _;         
}
```

Single underscore, and matching number of braces. Using correct indentation will help you spot similar issues.

I'd also recommend using an IDE/editor that has brace/bracket matching, or using a prettify-ing package.